# Reportlab table going outside Frame

Tags: python, pdf, pdf-generation, reportlab

I'm trying to port a project from Python 2 to Python 3 and have run into a Reportlab issue.

When placing a table in a frame using the Platypus flowable `KeepInFrame` and setting `mode='shrink'` the table shrinks to fit vertically but does not shrink to fit horizontally. Any horizontal shrinkage only occurs in the proportion to the vertical shrinkage. Vertically the `KeepInFrame` works as expected but horizontally it behaves as if `mode='continue'`.

Here is my relevant code

Early on I create a frame like this

```
markbook_frame = Frame(cm, 2*cm, 27.7*cm, 17*cm, leftPadding=0, bottomPadding=0,
              rightPadding=0, topPadding=0, id='markbook_frame', showBoundary=1)
```

Then I append my table to the story, and the table shows in the desired frame

```
story.append(FrameBreak())
table_story = []
t = Table(data, style=table_style)
table_story.append(t)
t_keep = KeepInFrame(0, 0, table_story, mode='shrink', hAlign='CENTER', vAlign='MIDDLE')
story.append(t_keep)
```

My code worked as expected with Python 2.7. I'm wondering if this problem arises from Reportlab's recent Python 3 port?

Comment: I've just confirmed that the issue seems to be with reportlab==3.1.8 which displays the same behaviour for both Python 2.7 code and Python 3.3 code. The Python 2.7 code still work with reportlab==2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation it says

> set fakeWidth to False to make _listWrapOn do the 'right' thing

So your code

```
    t_keep = KeepInFrame(0, 0, table_story, mode='shrink', hAlign='CENTER', vAlign='MIDDLE')
```

Should be

```
    t_keep = KeepInFrame(0, 0, table_story, mode='shrink', hAlign='CENTER', vAlign='MIDDLE', fakeWidth=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This was a bug with Report Lab which has been fixed since I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue **because I limited body width** as per the size of standard A4! Let the body get its native width, and hopefully on converting to pdf; they will shrink of its own.

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    /* width:21cm; height:29.7cm; */    /** i Just commented the size of body  **/
    color:#555;
    background:#fff;
    font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
</style>
```